# Solving multiple linear systems in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to use CUDA to solve linear systems from the finite element method of the form U = K^-1 F, where U is the displacement vector, K is the stiffness matrix and F is the force vector. I've had success with this using `cusolverSpDcsrlsvchol` for a single value of F, but now I want to solve for multiple load cases (so multiple values of F, but K stays the same).

The problem I'm having is that I don't want to repeatedly call `cusolverSpDcsrlsvchol`, as this will calculate the inverse of K each time, which is wasteful. How can I solve for multiple values of F, but only calculate the inverse of K one time?

Comment: I think the refactorization module of cuSolver could be used to reapply the same factorization to another rhs. You might also be interested in [Ginkgo](https://ginkgo-project.github.io/), an accelerated sparse Linear Algebra library which supports multiple rhs. It comes from the same lab that created LAPACK long ago (which in turn inspired cuSolver).

Comment: The refactorisation module is an option, but it still wouldn't be as efficient as possible, since the module is designed for problems with the same sparsity but different coefficients. In my case K is unchanged, so both the sparsity and the coefficients remain the same. I will look at Ginkgo, might be better suited for my needs.